# How to use a dropdown bar and ng-view

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I've looked at ng-view according to

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

However, I'm very unsure as to how I would incorporate the above with the dropdown menu.

Here's a few screenshots showing what the website currently looks like for reference.

imgur.com/a/NUVEe

Here's the code

index.html

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

      <div class="container">                 <!-- top intro part -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">  OPENCV 3.0.0</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <ng-view>
      <div class="row"> <!-- Dropdown menu  -->
    <div class="col-md-20">
      <div id="main">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2">Filter List:</label>
          <div class="col-md-5">
        <select class="form-control" 
            ng-options="filter for filter in filters" 
            ng-model="filter"
            ng-change="GoToOpenCVpage(filter)">
          <option value=""> Select Filter</option>
        </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </ng-view>

    <div id = "content"> <!-- stuff showing opencv filter goes in here -->
      <ng-view>

      </ng-view>
    </div>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

makegray.html (the html content I want to inject into index.html)

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

      <div class="container">                 <!-- top intro part -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"> MAKE GRAY</a>
    </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <form action="../php/makegray.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Select image to upload: 
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>


    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

angularJS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

/*app.factory("API", function($http) {
  return {
  getFilters: function(callback) {
  $http.get("filters.php").success(callback);
  }
  }
  });*/

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
    $scope.ListOfOpenCV = {};         // declare array
    // $scope.ListOfOpenCV.filter = "";  

    $scope.filters = ["MakeGray", "Sobel"];
    //$scope.ListOfOpenCV.filter = $scope.filters[0];

    $scope.GoToOpenCVpage = function(filter){
    if(filter === "MakeGray"){      
        //      window.location("pages/Canny.html");
        window.open("pages/MakeGray.html", "_blank","height = 400, width = 700"); 
    }
    };

});
```

Comment: You use ng-view when also using routing. That means you don't put anything as "content" in the element with ng-view, and you also configure your routeprovider with routes. Why do you have content in your ng-view, and where is your route configuration? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm still new to webdev and angularJS, what do you mean by "That means you don't put anything as "content" in the element with ng-view, and you also configure your routeprovider with routes."? 

Can  you give me an example of what you mean? I'm not asking you to solve my problem for me (I do want to learn this), but I would like an example of it in action. I have read the angularJS developer's guide and I'm still having a hard time understanding how to implement this.

Comment: That means you use [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) (look at the bottom `script.js` file and you'll see an example of routes and the correct usage of ng-view). What I mean is there should be no "inner html" in an ng-view, it's `<div ng-view></div>`, not `<div ng-view>content</div>`; the content is loaded using the routes set up in the `$routeProvider`.

Comment: I got it to work using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude and now I'm even more confused because I thought ngRoute would be involved in it. 

Can you explain why the above link's sample code works without using ngRoute?

Comment: No, ngInclude includes a template, you can use it for recursive code like a tree view for instance. ngRoute loads a template from a cache or from the server, but it gets loaded in one place (where the ng-view directive is located)